# How to use tensorRT in Yolov5?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorrt, yolov5

I want to optimize my trained model in Yolov5 using tensorRT. But am unable to find a proper way of doing so.Can any body tell show me how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) repository for `Yolo-V5`. It has a section dedicated to `tensorrt` deployment.

You can also learn about `tensorrt` inference using [C++](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-run-inference-using-tensorrt-c-api/) and [Python](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-convert-a-model-from-pytorch-to-tensorrt-and-speed-up-inference/)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/251

would you try:

```
python benchmarks.py --weights yolov5s.pt --imgsz 640 --device 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark is used for exporting and evaluating ALL export frameworks. Even the ones that has nothing to do with TenosrRT. Use:

```
python export.py --weights yolov5s.pt --include engine
```

for exporting your Yolov5 model to TensorRT